# (Payload was not valid JSON) trying to print to slack room in swift

Tags: ios, swift, slack-api

```
let str = "payload={'channel': '#bottest', 'username': 'garrettogrady', 'text': 'This post is coming from swift.'}"
    let strData = (str as NSString).dataUsingEncoding(NSUTF8StringEncoding)
    let cachePolicy = NSURLRequestCachePolicy.ReloadIgnoringLocalCacheData

    let url = NSURL(string: "web hook url (leaving it out for privacy reasons")

    var request = NSMutableURLRequest(URL: url!, cachePolicy: cachePolicy, timeoutInterval: 2.0)

    request.HTTPMethod = "POST"
    request.HTTPBody = strData
    println("printing to slack")
    var error : NSError? = nil
    if let data = NSURLConnection.sendSynchronousRequest(request, returningResponse: nil, error: &error) {
        let results = NSString(data:data, encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding)
        println(results)
    }
    else
    {
        println("data invalid")
        println(error)
    }
```

So when I run this code, I don't get in error. But when I print results, it says "Payload was not valid JSON"

Comment: I may be pushing an open door but… Your JSON is not correct ;)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Slack expects double quotes on JSONs. The result you're getting is from Slack rejecting your JSON as it's presently formed.

Here is code from my own stuff, which lets you incorporate variable values for the various fields, which I figure is your next step anyway.

```
let channel = "#bottest"
let username = "garrettogrady"
let text = "This post is coming from swift."
let payload = "payload={\"channel\": \"\(channel)\", \"username\": \"\(username!)\", \"text\": \"\(text)\""}"
```

EDIT: This question inspired me to create an object to implement the Slack webhook API. Here it is for anyone interested: https://github.com/pfj3/SwiftSlackbots

Comment: Well, JSON expects double quotes. Slack would be horribly broken if it accepted single quotes in JSON.

Answer (score 1):

Well, this is because your JSON is not valid, as stated by the error message.

**In the JSON string**, keys have to be inside double quotes; dictionaries are delimited with `{}` and arrays with `[]`. Also, use `:`, not `=`.

```
let str = "{\"payload\":{\"channel\": \"#bottest\", \"username\": \"garrettogrady\"}}"
```

You can check if your JSON string is valid by creating an object with it:

```
if let strData = (str as NSString).dataUsingEncoding(NSUTF8StringEncoding) {
    var error: NSError?
    if let json = NSJSONSerialization.JSONObjectWithData(strData, options: NSJSONReadingOptions.allZeros, error: &error) as? [String:AnyObject] {
        println(json)
    }
}
```

What's printed is the object representation of the JSON content (syntax look different of course, don't mix it up with the JSON syntax or the Swift syntax):

> ["payload": {
>       channel = "#bottest";
>       username = garrettogrady;
>   }]

Then you're sure that your JSON *string* is ok to be sent, because you were able to make an object with it.

Comment: Thank you so much!
The JSON is working, but its saying i need a text even though I have 
"{\"payload\":{\"channel\": \"#bottest\", \"text\": \"hey -- from swift\", \"username\": \"garrettogrady\"}}"